# Android program doesn't want to run - "Unfortunately, (myAppName) has stopped."

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to stackOverflow and Android development. Will someone please help me out?

I have followed **[this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm)** tutorial to open the camera from a button or imageView within a new app I currently work on, but when I want to run the application to test it, it gives me the following error on my android device; "Unfortunately, (myAppName) has stopped.". I use Eclipse as my IDE.

**LogCat:**

```
05-03 17:19:32.596: I/Process(785): Sending signal. PID: 785 SIG: 9
05-03 17:30:48.661: D/AndroidRuntime(1599): Shutting down VM
05-03 17:30:48.661: W/dalvikvm(1599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f3d2a0)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simon.cameratoets/com.simon.cameratoets.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at com.simon.cameratoets.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-03 17:30:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(1599):     ... 11 more
05-03 17:35:57.711: I/Process(1599): Sending signal. PID: 1599 SIG: 9
```

**My MainActivity:**

```
package com.simon.cameratoets;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imgFavorite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                open();
            }
        });
    }

    public void open(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simon.cameratoets"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.simon.cameratoets.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated, and I am sorry if this post was already been posted in the past. It is just unusual that the same thing happens when I want a button to go to another activity when using `Intent`, and I do make sure that the other activity is in the manifest file. In this case of the camera - I just followed the example from that link above, and it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` returns `null`.

Are you sure `activity_main.xml` contains an `ImageView` with id `imageView1`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. My imageView1 was in fragment_main.xml, the wrong xml file. I fixed it by put it into the activity_main.xml. It works as planned. Thanks! I would like to vote your answer up but I need 15 reputation, therefore I can't vote up, but thanks.I just noticed that I always work in my fragment_x.xml file and not in the actvity_x.xml which made it impossible to work